# How to change design at storyboard start using GUI Design studio

Tags: prototype

I hope this question belongs here...

I'm using GUI Design studio to prototype GUI design. Is there any way to specify that something should happen at the very begining of storyboard ?

Comment: This website is intended more for questions about user experience design, not specific questions about how to use a certain product.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you ask this question to Caretta Software, the creators of GUI design studio: http://www.carettasoftware.com/support.html. They'll be more able to help you.

Comment: … or [Super User](http://superuser.com/)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a free open source tool from http://pencil.evolus.vn/en-US/Home.aspx
I'am using this one.. It's really worth to use. If you have installed VS 2011 , you will see an Storyboard template in Powerpoint. You can easily do all prototypes. Here's my codeproject article http://www.codeproject.com/KB/office/PowerPointStoryBoard.aspx